# What's the advantages of using iterator in java

Tags: java, iterator

What's the advantages of using iterator in java?

We can always use for loop to iterate a set, list, etc. For example, we can always use:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sth.size(); i ++)
```

to iterate a collection.

Why/when do we use iterator?

Comment: No, we cannot always do it. What if the collection is a Map?

Comment: @RoyalBg `Map` isn't technically [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) :)

Comment: @Pshemo well, said that way you are right :) the `entrySet()` returns a collection, right?

Comment: @RoyalBg Yes, and this set will be Iterable which means we can use `for-each` loop on it :)